# Execution of threads with different certificate reference present in jks keystore

Tags: jmeter, keystore-access

Execution of threads with different certificate reference present in jks keystore.

When i am trying to execute jmeter script having multiple thread groups and want every individual thread group should pickup different certificate from key store its not working at all.
If I provided individual certificate 1st thread group and its loops execution is working fine.

**Scenario are:**

1.Thread group should have multiple users(threads) and some https upload request in multiple loop (working fine if single certificate details provided in system properties)

2.Multiple Thread group should have multiple users(threads) and some https upload request in multiple loop  execution of thread should call different certificate details from jks keystore provided in system. properties

Please suggest solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [Keystore Configuration element](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration) which scans the keystore for certificates so given you have multiple aliases there you should be able to use different SSL certificate for different virtual users.

[image: JMeter Keystore Configuration]

Make sure to set the following properties:

- in *system.properties*

  ```
  javax.net.ssl.keyStore=path_to_keystore
  javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=your keystore type (JKS or PCKS12)
  javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password_of_keystore
  ```
- in *user.properties*

  ```
  https.use.cached.ssl.context=false
  ```

More information: [How to Use Multiple Certificates When Load Testing Secure Websites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-multiple-certificates-when-load-testing-secure-websites)